# multiselect not selecting values programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

I'm having an issue with a DropDownList multiselect ([Reference](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)).

**What I want...**

I want to programmatically click some checkboxes from the dropdown using their values (for postback matters).

## **BRIEFING**

---

In 'Reference', I found out that there's a bug in jQuery, so I needed to do this ->

```
$("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function(){
    this.click();
});
```

So, I tried this and worked... then, I added the "[value='value']", and it worked. That's exactly what I needed.

```
$("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[value='value']").each(function(){
    this.click();
});
```

Here's what I did: I obtained an array with the values of the selected before postback (***consultantValues***). Then, I want to find the checkbox on the dropdown "Consultant" with a value from the array, and finally, click it.

**Code**->

```
for (var x = 0; x < consultantValues.length; x++) {
    var consultantSelected = ":checkbox[value='" + consultantValues[x] + "']";
    var doConsultantStringCode = $("id$='ddlConsultant']").multiselect("widget").find(consultantSelected);    
    for (var a = 0; a < doConsultantStringCode.length; a++) {
        doConsultantStringCode[a].click();
    }
}
```

This works like a charm :B
By the way, I use the "for" instead of the "each" because it runs faster.

## **PROBLEM**

---

In other dropdown, I try to do the same... it worked, but suddenly it stopped working :/

**Code** ->

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectedManagements.length; i++) {
   var checkboxValue = ":checkbox[value='" + selectedManagements[i] + "']";
   var findCheckbox = $("[id$='ddlManagement']").multiselect("widget").find(checkboxValue);
   for (var k = 0; k < findCheckbox.length; k++) {
     findCheckbox[k].click();
   }
}
```

I'm stuck with this :/

**NOTES**:

- What I was able to see, the findCheckbox has length = 0... don't understand why now has 0 length when before had 1...
- the dropdowns are ASP controls.
- If you need any extra info, just let me know

Comment: Should be `$("[id$='ddlManagement']")`, no? You're missing a `[`. Not sure why it had an element in it before, though. Run it in firebug to see what it returns.

Comment: Sry, I'll edit it now... I just misstyped on the post ^^U
On the code, it's well written :P

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of emulating clicks, why don't you just add `checked="checked"` attribute? This is actually way too hack-ish to trigger DOM events that user did not initiate.

Just do this:

```
$("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function(){
    this.attr({ checked: "checked" });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that!

Although I've already tested it with checked="checked", it didn't worked. It said the method doesn't exist.

Luckily, when I managed to make it work, found something similar to `attr()` the `setAttribute()` method, and used `setAttribute('selected', true)`.

Thank you for helping improving my code :)

Comment: Oh wait, you're using Prototype not jQuery. I didn't realize that. Correct, they don't have `attr` method. Other than that it should have worked, and basically it's never a good idea as I said to emulate DOM events unless they are triggered by user. And your problem is definitely not in the fact that it does not work in general - problem is somewhere in the code. Maybe add `debugger` somewhere and see what is going on in the console.

Comment: I already found the problem.
As I post as an answer, the problem was that someone put my code before the configuration of the multiselect (I'm not working alone :P)... therefore, my code never finds anything, and it does nothing... and then the dropdown becomes multiselect.

I'll put this as an accepted answer, since you wrote valuable info. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad you found the cause, and I appreciate accepting my answer )

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve this.

I work with some people, and we all work on the same site.
The problem was that someone moved the part where the multiselect was set (with it's configuration) AFTER my code...

So, my code was looking for something that still didn't exist, so it did nothing.

Two possible things to do:

- 1: Put the code that selects programmatically after the code that sets the multiselect.
- 2: Make the dropdown multiselect. Then add your code, and finally add the multiselect configuration. (what I finally did XD)

2: Example:

```
        management.attr("multiple", 'multiple');

        if (selectedManagements != null) {
            for (var z = 0; z < selectedManagements.length; z++) {
                var checkboxValue = "[value='" + selectedManagements[z] + "']";
                var findSelectedCheckbox = management.children(checkboxValue);
                for (var lambda = 0; lambda < findSelectedCheckbox.length; lambda++) {
                    findSelectedCheckbox[lambda].setAttribute('selected', true);
                }
            }
        } 

           [...]

            management.multiselect({
                selectedList: 2,
                noneSelectedText: 'Select a management',
                width: 300
            }).multiselectfilter();
```

PS: I thank @mvbl-fst for helping improving my code :)